# looping the class in each Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, frontend, each

I have the following DIV structure :

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>Content1<div>
  <div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>Content2<div>
</div>
```

> In one of my Jquery operation I am Removing all the content of
>   **mainDiv**

```
 strHtmlNewChildHtml = '<div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>New Content1<div><div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>New Content2</div>';

 $("#mainDiv").html(''); 
 $("#mainDiv").html(strHtmlNewChildHtml);
```

> and adding the New Html using looping the class name.

```
$('.childElement').each( function() {
//It is looping 4 times while new HTML having only 2 divs
 });
```

**My Question :** As I have removed the old 2 child elements and after adding the 2 new child elements while the loop is running 4 times ?

Comment: `$('childElement')` wouldn't loop a single time, actually

Comment: What is `childElement`

Comment: there's probably a lot more wrong with the question too - like, what is `strHtmlNewChildHtml`

Comment: show childElement html .

Comment: @Harshal Please mention what *strHtmlNewChildHtml* contents are ?

Comment: Maybe you need `#mainDiv .childElement` selector.

Comment: problem with `pseudo code` is you get pseudo help giving pseudo answers :p

Comment: that makes us all     psuedo debuggers  :P

Comment: you can try my code hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery call `$('.childElement')` will look the elements up *at the moment of the call*. So if at this point you have 4 `.childElement`s in your code, then it will loop 4 times.

Comment: so what changes i need to make to run it correctly only 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks your strHtmlNewChildHtml having wrong html structure. I just modified it working as expected two loops.

```js
 strHtmlNewChildHtml = "<div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>New Content1</div><div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>New Content2</div>";

 $("#mainDiv").html(''); 
 $("#mainDiv").html(strHtmlNewChildHtml);
$('.childElement').each( function() {
console.log("start");

console.log($(this).html());
console.log("end");

//It is looping 4 times while new HTML having only 2 divs
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>Content1<div>
  <div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>Content2<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
strHtmlNewChildHtml = "<div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>New Contentx<div><div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>New Contenty<div>";

$("#mainDiv").html(''); 
$("#mainDiv").html(strHtmlNewChildHtml);
 
$('.childElement').each(function(i){
   console.log(i); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>Content1<div>
  <div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>Content2<div>
</div>
```

Here you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is not close properly.

```js
var strHtmlNewChildHtml = "<div id='childDiv1 ' class='childElement '>New Content1</div><div id='childDiv2 ' class='childElement '>New Content2</div>";

$("#mainDiv").html('');
$("#mainDiv").html(strHtmlNewChildHtml);

$('.childElement').each(function(index, item) {
  alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>Content1
  </div>
  <div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>Content2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strHtmlNewChildHtml = "<div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>New Content1<div><div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>New Content2<div>";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mainDiv").html(''); 
  $("#mainDiv").html(strHtmlNewChildHtml);
 
  $('.childElement').each( function() {
    alert('loop_check');
    //It is looping 4 times while new HTML having only 2 divs
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>Content1</div>
  <div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>Content2</div>
</div>
```

You can specify like this , try this :

```
$('#mainDiv').children('.childElement').each( function() {

   // hopefully it works.

});
```

Also noticed that your div is not closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it will run only twice (if you call these function in the order you posted above).
Notice that i fixed some typos you had in the markup and code.

```js
strHtmlNewChildHtml = '<div id="childDiv1" class="childElement">New Content1</div><div id="childDiv2" class="childElement">New Content2</div>';

 $("#mainDiv").html(''); 
 $("#mainDiv").html(strHtmlNewChildHtml);
 
 $('.childElement').each( function(index,element) {
  //It is NOT looping 4 times while new HTML having only 2 divs
  // It is looping twice!
  console.log('iteration ' + index);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div id='childDiv1' class='childElement'>Content1<div>
  <div id='childDiv2' class='childElement'>Content2<div>
</div>
```